# Difference in displaying inner div between IE and Chrome

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I have this code that has one "outerDIV" that contains an "innerDIV". On chrome the "innerDIV" size is 491px, whereas on IE it is 425px (same as outerDIV). Hence, on Chrome I can see the first two children of "innerdiv": "My test string #1" and "test2". But for IE I can only see the first child.

I am not quite sure what the "right" behavior should be, as firefox does the same as IE. However I would like to have IE do the same as Chrome.

I have been experimenting with some css styles (mainly overflow and display), but still can't make it right: IE will expand its height instead of its width to make the elements fit.

Can you guys help me figure out a way to change the css so that IE will wraps the div elements inline? As a restriction though, I cannot change the width on the HTML. As a benefit, I am using a css that only loads for IE to patch these kind of IE inconsistencies. The same css will NOT load for chrome, so I don't need to worry about messing with chrome when changing the IE CSS. Thanks in advance!

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">

        <!--

            body {
                font-family: helvetica;
            }


            .myContainer {
                overflow: hidden;
                border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
                font-size: 14pt;
                height: 49px;
                line-height: 49px;
                overflow: hidden;
                display: block;
            }

            .myContainer > DIV {
                float: left;
                white-space: nowrap;
                display: block;
            }

            .myContainer .item:first-child {
                padding-left: 10px;
            }

            .myContainer .item {
                float: left;
                padding-right: 32px;
            }

        -->

    </style>

    </head>

        <body>

            <div id="outerDIV" class="myContainer" style="display: block; width: 425px;">
                <div id="innerDIV">
                    <div class="item">
                        --------My test string #1--------
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        ------test2-------
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        test
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: var len = innerDiv.childNodes.length,
                  icnWidth = 0,
                  i;
                                  
                 for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
                  icnWidth += innerDiv.childNodes[i].offsetWidth;                                   
                 }
                 
                 innerDiv.style.width = (icnWidth + 1) + 'px'; //Safety measure due to decimal points not being rounded the right way by the browser...

Answer (score 3):

You need a `doctype` tag on your page, otherwise it will be rendered in quirks mode.

What that means exactly differs from browser to browser, but basically it tries to be compatible with very old browsers. In IE it triggers the [non-standard box model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug), which would explain the differences in size.

Look at the [W3C recommended list of doctype declarations](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html) for a doctype tag to use.

Comment: Thanks! I have tried using the doctype, as well as making sure I am running IE with Browser Mode: IE9 + Document Mode: IE9 standards. However the results are still different from Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

set the width of `.item` ... container `overflow: hidden` hides the items which are shown verticaly because the width is more than a 'line' of container can show. When using floating is good to have the width set. DOCTYPE is very important to be set too. I personaly use `loose.dtd` which gives good competability.

Comment: Is there any way to do it without setting the width explicitly though, just as with Chrome?

Comment: You could set a relative width, for example width:33%, but it's good to be set.

Comment: Thank you. The problem with that approach is that all items have different width. I would need to calculate widths from javascript, but the whole idea is that instead of assigning the widths bottom-up, css would assign them by itself "top-down" (i.e. I assign width for "outerDIV" and chrome is assigning the sizes for "inner div" and all its children).

Comment: It looks to me that "white-space: nowrap;" is doing the trick for Chrome. However it does not for IE.

Answer (score 0):

I could not solve it purely with css. For IE, seems like the only way to fix this is to have the "innerDIV" element to have a width >= the sum of it's children offsetWidth. So I just added this to my JS code (special case for IE):

```
var len = innerDiv.childNodes.length,
          innerDivWidth = 0,
          i;

 for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
    innerDiv += innerDiv.childNodes[i].offsetWidth;                                             
 }

 innerDiv.style.width = (innerDiv + 1) + 'px';  //Safety measure to make up for the decimal places. I guess we could write this line in a better way by rounding up, etc.
```